# Magento 2 How to observe cart price in JS Component

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I want to show amount after which free shipping will be available in mini cart like below

[image]

For that I override minicart.phtml in view/frontend/layout/defaul.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" template="Vendor_Module::cart/minicart.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

And create my own ui component fst.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (uiComponent, ko, customerData) {
    return uiComponent.extend({
        _config: '',
        _element: '',

        initialize: function (config, element) {
            this._super();
            this._config = config;
            this._element = element;
        },
        myConf: function () {
            return this._config;
        },
        getPrice: function () {
            return this._config.min_price;
        },
        isEnable: function () {
            return this._config.is_enable;
        }
    });
});
```

And a template file fst.html

```
<p data-bind="if: isEnable()">Please shop <strong data-bind="text: getPrice()"></strong> more for free shipping.</p>
```

I call this component in minicart.phtml

```
         .
         .
         .
    <div class="block block-minicart"
         data-role="dropdownDialog"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "timeout": "2000",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":[]}}'>
         /* Render My template file */
        <div id="fst" data-bind="scope: 'fst'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate()   --> <!--  /ko  -->
        </div> ...
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-block='minicart']": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
    },
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= $block->escapeJs(
            $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))
        ) ?>"
    },
    "#fst": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "fst": {
                    "component": "Vendor_Module/js/fst",
                    "template": "Vendor_Module/fst",
                    "config": {
                        "min_price": "500",
                        "is_enable": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

With the above code I am getting a static output like above screen shot. But now I want to make this value dynamic whenever cart get refresh. I want to remove cart value from free shipping limit. How can I create an KO observer who always give me cart total and I can update the message.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change my ui component like this.

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (uiComponent, ko, customerData) {
    return uiComponent.extend({
        _config: '',
        _element: '',

        initialize: function (config, element) {
            this._super();
            this.cart = customerData.get('cart');
            this._config = config;
            this._element = element;
        },
        myConf: function () {
            return this._config;
        },
        getPrice: function () {
            var self = this;
            return ko.computed(function() {
                return self._config.min_price - self.cart().subtotalAmount;
            });
        },
        isEnable: function () {
            return this._config.is_enable;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explained what you changed please? It will be more helpful for others that way.

Comment: this.cart = customerData.get('cart');
this line give me computed (observable) cart object.